# How to purchase Lion OS without going to Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I would like to purchase Lion, but the Mac App Store requires a credit card, and I don't have one. Are there any other options which don't require a credit card?

Comment: See [How can I buy apps in the App Store without a credit card?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/how-can-i-buy-apps-in-the-app-store-without-a-credit-card)

Comment: its not available in my country. Any other alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to note, you can (at least in the UK) use the App Store with a debit card.

However, if you don't have one of those either, and you're not having any issues with OSX 10.6, why not continue using it for now? In August, Apple will start selling 10.7 on a USB drive, which you can purchase with cash in an Apple Store.

Comment: I dont have those cards. I emailed apple, but must went thru a troublesome way to send them an email. They really make users life harder............ Looks like I have no choice but to wait until August 2011.

Comment: Where did you hear that they will sell 10.7 on USB drives?!

Comment: @Samantha Catania - Uh.... Apple - http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/07/20Mac-OS-X-Lion-Available-Today-From-the-Mac-App-Store.html `later this August, Lion will be made available on a USB thumb drive through the Apple Store® (www.apple.com) for $69 (US).`

Answer (score 5):

As someone already answered, you could wait till August and buy Lion in a USB Flash Drive, but that will cost you $30 more, besides the wait.

You could buy iTunes Gift Cards to put some credit in your iTunes Store account (and even open an account using using an iTunes Gift Card as the payment method). If you don't have a place nearby where to buy them, you can buy through eBay and pay with PayPal using your debit card.

Some vendor will send the iTunes Gift Card in a matter of minutes, through e-mail, and don't charge much more than in a store.

Comment: $40 more :). $29.99 -> $69.99

Answer (score 1):

At least here in Finland they accept [ClickAndBuy](http://clickandbuy.com), which in turn accepts some debit cards (like Visa Electron). You can also add funds to the account with a bank transfer.

Answer (score 1):

I used a prepaid MasterCard; you go to your local bank & you buy one, they come in denominations of €50,75,100 (or your countries equivalent). They work similarly to cellphone top-up card (for prepaid contract obviously)

Comment: Yeah there are also other cards you can buy with cash like the Visa Vanilla and the like. This would allow anyone who is 18 buy it in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

lpacheco has the simplest solution, buy a gift card, you can get these everywhere from bookstores to supermarkets etc.  Create an iTunes account if you don't already have one, and load the credit up.